# mysqli_connect not connecting to localhost

Tags: php, mysql

As title suggests, I'm getting the following error when using mysqli_connect:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/username/Sites/test.php on linez 2

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/username/Sites/test.php on line 2
Could not connect:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(‘localhost’, ‘username’, ‘password’);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

My firewall is turned off and apache2 is turned on, I am able to view localhost/Username/Sites/test.php as well as logging into mysql using localhost.

Comment: Standard, username is root, and there is not password. Your definitions up there are read now as localhost (works) username as username and password as password. Thus you also missed the fact you have to connect to a database, which is the fourth value within in the mysqli connect function.

Comment: `mysqli_connect` has four parameters. You forgot the fourth param. i.e. `mysqli_connect(‘localhost’, ‘username’, ‘password’, 'your_database_name')`.

Answer (score 3):

from where you bring those quotes ? you should use single quotes.

try this:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password'); //you forgot the database
```

and why you mix between mysqli and mysql ?

Like that you connect to database:

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

please read good the documentation here https://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db

Answer (score 1):

If you are using textedit app that is built into OS X then, **disable**/ **uncheck** the feature called "Smart Quotes" from the preferences pane of TextEdit and then You will have to replace all the existing quotes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem as well but none of the answers helped.

Despite what many answers say, the database name is not mandatory as a 4th parameter, as per the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php - all the parameters are optional.

**For me what solved it was to double check the database host** as in my code it is dynamic and it was picking up wrongly the distant database host instead of localhost.

```
$mysqli = IS_LOCAL ? 
    new mysqli($settings->localDBhost, $settings->localUser, $settings->localPassword)
    : new mysqli($settings->DBhost, $settings->DBuser, $settings->DBpassword);
```

(After I created a virtual host, I had to add it to the `IS_LOCAL` constant's condition)

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysqli_connect(‘localhost’, ‘username’, ‘password’);
```

should be

```
$link = mysqli_connect(‘localhost’, ‘username’, ‘password’, 'yourdatabase');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'phonehome','3306','/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock') OR die('Could not connect to database. Verify connection.php settings and SQL DB is running. Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());
```

Which is defining your Hostname, port, username, password, db and mySQL socket, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't remember (I think I read it somewhere else on SO, actually), when you connect to `'localhost'` using mysqli(), you actually have to specify what port number you're connecting on as well:

`$dbconn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', /*your username*/, /*your password*/, /*your database name*/);`

3306 is, if I remember correctly, the default port, but even so you need to specify that in this case - literally only when you try to connect on localhost, but for some reason that's how it is.

Also - I noticed that in your original code your quotation marks in your `mysqli_connect(...)` line look different from those in your other code lines. This may just be something that happened in stack overflow when you wrote out your question, but if it's not and those different quotation marks are in your code as well, then you may need to change them to the same ones as in your later code.